# spring portlet mvc form:select bind to list

Tags: spring, select, binding, portlet

I am using spring mvc portlet for one of my applications. I have a problem in binding a dynamically filled list box with the List collection in Controller.

Conference.java:

```
public class Conference {
    private List<Patient> scheduledPatients;
    //getter/setter for scheduledPatients
}
```

saveParticipants.jsp

```
<form:select path="scheduledParticipants" items="${scheduledParticipants}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="name" />
```

The scheduledParticipants list data is filled with the data selected from another listbox and moved to scheduledParticipants listbox.

On submitting an action request, I am unable to get newly filled scheduledParticipants bound in Controller action mapping. The ModelAttribute is the Conference pojo.

We have used InitBinder for the binding the data to scheduledParticipants. 
Still I am unable to get the selected Participants data on controller.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use `initBinder` for binding lists of objects to their bean counterparts.

For Spring MVC 3, see the following code:

```
@InitBinder<br/>
public void setTestBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
   dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new TestPropertyEditor(List.class, true));
}
```

We need to write a `TestPropertyEditor` (extends `CustomCollectionEditor`) which will have a `convertElement` method to convert the string to an appropriate object.

Refer to the Spring MVC framework reference documentation for variants of `initBinder`....